# Работа со вторым сетевым интерфейсом Google Cloud platform

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, ip-address, виртуальная-машина

На GCP есть VM instance с двумя сетевыми интерфейсами.Проблема заключается в том, что со втогоро интерфейса никакого респонса.

В правилах брендмауэра допускается 3 порта: 22, 80, 443

Ось - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Добавил второй сетевой как дефолтный:

```
user@vm-inst:~$ ip route sh    
default via 10.15.0.1 dev eth0 
10.15.0.1 dev eth0  scope link 
10.16.0.1 dev eth1  scope link 


user@vm-inst:~$ ip ad show
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1460 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:01:0a:0f:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.15.0.2/32 brd 10.15.0.2 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1460 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:01:0a:10:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.16.0.2/32 brd 10.16.0.2 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

jnettop показывает что на второй интефейс никакого входящего трафика нет, хотя в то же время я пробую заходить через SSH и браузер.

Как мне понять на каком месте отсеивается трафик и как это исправить? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Всё правильно. Так работает маршрутизация. А чего ты хочешь добиться?

Comment: Я хочу чтобы я мог через второй интерфейс заходить как по ssh, так и через веб. Но пока север не отвечает при попытке зайти на него

Comment: Роутингом такая задача не решается, потребуется настройка сетевой трансляции адресов.